# Moq: Verify object in parameter null reference

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to Moq a synchronization process, but I'm having issues with one specific part.

In my method I'm trying to Moq I perform the following:

```cs
public class SyncManager
{
    private IPubHttpClient _pubHttpClient;
    private ILogService _logService;
    private Ilogger _logger;

    public SyncManager(IPubHttpClient pubClient, ILogService logService ILogger<SyncManager> logger)
    {
        _pubHttpClient = pubClient;
        _logService = logService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Sync()
    {
        var syncStatus = SyncStatus.Error;

        // get logs
        var logs = await _logService.GetLogs();

        foreach (var log in logs)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(log.CostCode))
               syncStatus = await GetAndSendCost(log);
            elseif
               syncStatus = await GetAndSendSort(log);         
        }
    }

    private async Task<SyncStatus> GetAndSendCost(Log log)
    {
        var cost = new Cost
        {
            CostCode = log.CostCode,
            CostName = log.Description,
            Active = log.Active
        };

        await _pubHttpClient.Push(new EventModel { Cost = cost, MessageType = log.Type.GetDescription() });

        return SyncStatus.Success;
    }

    private async Task<SyncStatus> GetAndSendSort(Log log)
    {
        var sort = new Sort
        {
            SortCode = log.SortCode,
            SortName = log.Description,
            Active = log.Active
        };

        await _pubHttpClient.Push(new EventModel { Sort = sort, MessageType = log.Type.GetDescription() });

        return SyncStatus.Success;
    }
}

public class Log
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string SortCode { get; set; }
    public string CostCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public AuditType Type { get; set; }
}

public class EventModel 
{
    public Cost Cost { get; set; }
    public Sort Sort { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}

public enum AuditType
{
    [Description("CREATE")]
    Create = 0,
    [Description("UPDATE")]
    Update = 1,
    [Description("DELETE")]
    Delete = 2
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                   .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                   .First()
                   .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?
                   .Description ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My tests I have set up to like this:

```cs
    public class SyncManagerTests
    {
        public readonly Mock<IPubHttpClient> _pubClientMock = new();
        public readonly Mock<ILogService> _logServiceMock = new();

        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_Sync()
        {
            var mockedCost = new Cost { Active = Status.Active, CostCode = "0000", CostName = "UNIT TEST" };
            var mockedSort = new Sort { Active = Status.Active, SortCode = "0001", SortName = "UNIT TEST" };
            var mockedLogs = new List<Log> { 
                new Log { CostCode = mockedCost.CostCode, Description = mockedCost.CostName, Active = mockedCost.Active, Id = 1 },
               new Log { SortCode = mockedSort.SortCode, Description = mockedSort.CostName, Active = mockedSort.Active, Id = 2 },
            };

            _logServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLogs()).ReturnsAsync(mockedLogs).Verifiable();
            _pubClientMock.Setup(p => p.Push(It.Is<EventModel>(x => x.Cost == mockedCost && x.MessageType == "CREATE"))).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();

            var syncManager = new SyncManager(_pubClientMock.Object, _logServiceMock.Object, Mock.Of<ILogger<SyncManager>>());

            await syncManager.Sync();

            _pubClientMock.Verify(p => p.Push(It.Is<EventModel>(
                x => x.Cost.CostName == mockedCost.CostName
                && x.Cost.CostCode == mockedCost.CostCode
                && x.Cost.Active == mockedCost.Active
                && x.MessageType == "CREATE")));
        }
    }
```

When I run this test, every piece of code is called correctly and while debugging I see that the `EventModel object` is being created with the correct values.

However in my test when I call `_pubClientMock.Verify();` I get a `System.NullReferenceException`:
It seems like the `x.Cost` is NULL here.

Any idea why this property would be NULL or what I'm doing wrong here?

So to iterate again, actually calling the `.Sync()` and stepping through the code with the debugger works perfectly. It's the `_pubClientMock.Verify` that fails with with a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: `x.Cost == mockedCost` in your mock predicate is checking reference equality, not value.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Is there a way around this? If in the .Setup() I do `x => x.Cost.CostCode == mockedCost.CostCode` Then I get a nullreference exception in my `await _pubHttpClient.Push(EventModel { Cost = cost, MessageType = log.Type.GetDescription() });`.
If I later do a .Verify() in the unit test `_pubClientMock.Verify(p => p.Push(It.Is<AnalyticalCombinationEvent>(x => x.Cost.CostCode == mockedCost.CostCode...` I also get a null reference exception.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear as too much supporting code was omitted.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure what you mean, but I added some more code in case that would help.

Comment: @Schoof `MessageType = log.Type.GetDescription()` Based on the shown code, that is a potential location to get a NRE. But that property does not exist in the shown example for `Log` type. Like I said before. We are not seeing everything. This question is most likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Schoof After trying to guess all the types and members still missing from your example I tried running your test and it fails in your extension method. Clearly I guessed wrong with some of the types since I will have no clue what your actual code is like

Comment: @Schoof Ok I was finally able to recreate your null reference issue. Investigating now. In future I would suggest you make sure you provide all the necessary code to reproduce the actual problem. It will save a lot of time for yourself and those volunteering to help you .

Comment: @Schoof All I had to do was add `x => x.Cost != null.....` to the verify to get the test to pass.

Comment: @Schoof check provided answer. note the comments in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the one of the already provided answers I would suggest relaxing the setup to avoid issues with referential equality by using `It.IsAny`. This will allow the test case to flow to completion.

As for the null reference error in the Verification, because the updated example will have a situation where one of the event models will have a null `Cost` property value, you will need to check for null when verifying the predicate

```
[TestClass]
public class SyncManagerTests {
    public readonly Mock<IPubHttpClient> _pubClientMock = new Mock<IPubHttpClient>();
    public readonly Mock<ILogService> _logServiceMock = new Mock<ILogService>();

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Sync() {
        var mockedCost = new Cost { Active = Status.Active, CostCode = "0000", CostName = "UNIT TEST" };
        var mockedSort = new Sort { Active = Status.Active, SortCode = "0001", SortName = "UNIT TEST" };
        var mockedLogs = new List<Log> {
            new Log { CostCode = mockedCost.CostCode, Description = mockedCost.CostName, Active = mockedCost.Active, Id = 1 },
           new Log { SortCode = mockedSort.SortCode, Description = mockedSort.SortName, Active = mockedSort.Active, Id = 2 },
        };

        _logServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLogs()).ReturnsAsync(mockedLogs);
        _pubClientMock
            .Setup(p => p.Push(It.IsAny<EventModel>())) //<-- NOTE THIS
            .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

        var syncManager = new SyncManager(_pubClientMock.Object, _logServiceMock.Object, Mock.Of<ILogger<SyncManager>>());

        await syncManager.Sync();

        _pubClientMock.Verify(p => p.Push(It.Is<EventModel>(
            x => x.Cost != null //<-- NOTE THE NULL CHECK
            && x.Cost.CostName == mockedCost.CostName
            && x.Cost.CostCode == mockedCost.CostCode
            && x.Cost.Active == mockedCost.Active
            && x.MessageType == "CREATE")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more detail about Log you pass through GetAndSendCost() maybe the problem comes from that part, you can use It.IsAny<EventModel>()

```
// Arrange 
Mock<IPubHttpClient> _pubClientMock = new Mock<IPubHttpClient>();

_pubClientMock.Setup(p => p.Push(It.IsAny<EventModel>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();

var syncManager = new SyncManager(_pubClientMock.Object, Mock.Of<ILogger<SyncManager>>());

// Act
await syncManager.Sync();

// Assert
_pubClientMock.Verify(p => p.Push(It.Is<EventModel>(
 x => x.Cost.CostName == mockedCost.CostName
      && x.Cost.CostCode == mockedCost.CostCode
      && x.Cost.Active == mockedCost.Active
      && x.MessageType == "CREATE")));
```

Comment: Sure, I've added that information to the question. Using It.IsAny unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: you have to provide more exactly code the problem occur, I see the implementation of SyncManager have changed with the new parameter.